# Objective-C: Using inheritance and calling methods in Child Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

I'm setting up inheritance.

I have a parent class that has a method that calls a block.  Once the block returns, I need it to call an over-written method in the child class.

When I setup breakpoints, upon failure, the block is calling the method in the parent class.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Parent Class

.h

```
@interface BaseClass : UITableViewController
-(void)userModelUpdated
-(void)updateModel
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation BaseClass

-(void)userModelUpdated
{} //this is left blank intentionally as a hook


-(void)updateModel
{
   //Here is s Block 
    [EndPoint updateUserModel:self.userModel successBlock:^{
    //Do Something
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error, NSArray *errorArray) {    
       [self userModelUpdated];  // I want to call the method in the child class
      // but when I setup the break points, it calls the method in the parent class
    }
}
```

Child Class

.h

```
@interface childClass : BaseClass
```

.m

```
@implementation ChildClass

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self updateModel];
}

-(void)userModelUpdated
{
  // update UILabels Here    
}
```

Comment: You have `@implementation ChildClass` twice: In the Parent Class .m file and in the Child Class .m file. - Is that the actual code or some copy/paste error?

Comment: Sorry. Actual code is really messy so I simplified it.  I fixed the implementation.

Comment: Are you sure that the object in question is an instance of `ChildClass`? Have you set a breakpoint in `updateModel` and checked the class of `self`?

Comment: Hm, insert some intentionaly crashing thing like abort() into your method -[ChildClass userModelUpdated] to ensure that it is really not being run.

Comment: Try putting the declarion of -(void) userModelUpdated in the @interface section for ChildClass

Comment: One more guess: re-check that .m files of both of your classes are included into the target you are running!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `self` is an instance of `ChildClass` when `updateModel` is invoked, then the ChildClass's implementation of `-userModelUpdated` **will be executed**.

If it isn't, then it is because you probably have an instance of `BaseClass` or you have a misspelling.

Add this to all methods:

```
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

That'll log exactly what is going on at every step of the way.

Comment: Seems like I have an instance of BaseClass.  Why do I have an instance of BaseClass when the ChildClass is calling the Block?

Comment: Did you check to see if `self` in `updateModel` is an instance of `ChildClass`?

Comment: Even though the Child class is what calls the block, I don't understand how am I ending up with an instance of the BaseClass.

Comment: @user1107173 Did you put the logging in the `updateModel` method?  That symbol looks more like the symbol describing where the block is declared.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your code that is creating an instance of this class family is wrong, and is creating a base class object instead of a child class object. Post the code that creates the object and invokes the method on it.

Answer (score -1):

Blocks are compiled with the scope of the code where they are. In that case, you should make the block a property and use set/get to setup is within the child class. Then it will work as you intend.

Comment: Huh? An object doesn't change its class depending on the method where it is used.